# Adding methods to arrays of custom objects

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add a method an an `array` like this.

```java
    Position[] positions = new Position[10];
    Position pos = positions.getPosAt(x, y);
```

I know this can be accomplished like:

```java
   Position pos = getPosAt(positions, x, y)
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish the first method.

Comment: No, not in java.

Comment: As an alternative, you could create a class (wrapper) which would contain the `positions` and in which you would implement the method. But, again, this is just an alternative to the problem that in Java you cannot do that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: I'm really having trouble to understand your question because it looks like you're mixing arrays and classes in a way which is completely unintended and unusual.

Comment: [Can be done in Kotlin with extension methods](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a class handler for this, like this PositionArray class (name it as you would like):

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {

        Position[] positions = new Position[10];

        positions[0] = new Position(5, 10);
        positions[1] = new Position(11, 18);
        positions[2] = new Position(20, 7);

        PositionArray pa = new PositionArray(positions);

        System.out.println(pa.getPosAt(5, 10)); // Position{x=5, y=10}

    }
}
```

```
class PositionArray {

    private Position[] positions;

    public PositionArray(Position[] positions) {
        this.positions = positions;
    }

    public Position getPosAt(int x, int y) {

        for (Position p : positions) {
            if (!Objects.isNull(p)) {
                System.out.println(p.getX() + " " + p.getY());
                if (p.getX() == x && p.getY() == y) {
                    return p;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
class Position {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Position{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + '}';
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Java.  You could possibly create your own class that contained an array of `Position` objects and provides e.g. `get` methods, but there is no way whatsoever to add methods to classes you do not control, including all array types.